# Can't find reference to Automapper in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, reference, automapper, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an MVC project in C#. I removed reference to automapper by mistake and I cannot find it when I choose to add reference to that project. reinstalling the package in nuget doesn't fix the problem too(It says the package is allready installed). then how can I recover the reference to automapper?

Answer (score 0):

removing the  tag (with id="AutoMapper") from packages.config in project and installing AutoMapper with nuget console again solved the problem